# does entropy of half cell reaction change with stoichiometry

Tags: electrochemistry, reduction-potential

the standard potential of the following cell is 0.23V at 288K and 0.21V at 308K.

Pt|H2|HCl(aq)||AgCl|Ag

calculate $\Delta{S}$ .

I know that $\Delta{S}=nF(\frac{\Delta{E}}{\Delta{T}})$ here n is the number of moles of electrons exchanged in the reaction, but doesn't the number of moles of electrons exchanged depend on the stoichiometry of the reaction for example
$$ H_2+2AgCl\rightarrow2 Ag+2HCl$$
here n is 2
but if I write the reaction as

$\frac{1}{2}H_ 2+AgCl\rightarrow$ Ag + HCl

here n is 1 so wouldnt the entropy change with stoichiometry

Comment: Yes, it would change. $\Delta S$ should be calculated for the reaction *as written*.